# Laravel routes continue url slug

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing, laravel-5.6

I don't know how to make 1 route display url/something, and the next route display url/something/anotherthing

Right now except the third route everything works fine. 
It displays the url/company_name and it shows a view with another list of links.
I want when I click one link to pass $table_name, $company_name to the next view but I also want the url to be url/company_name/table_name.

I have this in my home.blade that display some links:

```
@foreach($companies as  $data)                   
<a href="{{ route('show_tables',$company_name = $data->name )}}" class="btn btn-primary" >
{{$data->name }}
</a>
@endforeach
```

When I click the link in controller I have this:

```
   public function index($company_name) {
        $tables = DB::connection($company_name)->table('tables')->get();
        return view('apps.welcome', compact('tables', 'company_name'));
    }
```

and this is my apps.welcome.blade view:

```
        <div class="card-body">
            @csrf
            @foreach($tables as  $data)                   
            <a href="{{ route('choose_table',$table_name = $data->name)}}" class="btn btn-primary" >
                {{$data->name }}
            </a>
            @endforeach
```

And this are my web routes :

```
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('/{company_name}', 'Apps\WelcomeController@index')->name('show_tables');
Route::get('{company_name}/{table_name}', 'Apps\SetupController@index')->name('choose_table');
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Missing required parameters for [Route: choose_table] [URI: {company_name}/{table_name}]. (View: apps.welcome.blade)
```

Comment: try this `route('choose_table', ['company_name' => $company_name,  'table_name' => $data->name]);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `choose_table` route in app.welcome.blade.php with one parameter missing:

```
<a href="{{ route('choose_table',$table_name = $data->name)}}" class="btn btn-primary" >
    {{$data->name }}
</a>
```

Your route actually requires 2 parameters i.e. `company_name` & `table_name`:

```
Route::get('{company_name}/{table_name}', 'Apps\SetupController@index')->name('choose_table');
```

Use both parameters in your route (as mentioned by @rkj in comment):

```
route('choose_table', ['company_name' => $company_name, 'table_name' => $data->name]);
```

Otherwise, make your **2nd** parameter as optional:

```
Route::get('{company_name}/{table_name?}', 'Apps\SetupController@index')->name('choose_table');
```

but if you are doing this, you must give default value for optional parameter in controller.

[Optional Parameters](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#parameters-optional-parameters)

Answer (score 1):

You need two parameters `company_name` and `table_name` but you are passing `table_name` only.
Wither pass company_name also or remove `{company_name}` as below.

```
 <a href="{{ route('choose_table',$table_name = $data->name)}}" class="btn btn-primary" >
     {{$data->name }}
</a>

Route::get('{table_name}', 'Apps\SetupController@index')->name('choose_table');
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the last parameter for the route so you need to pass that as a parameter.

If you want optional second parameter you can append a question mark to the named parameter in the route (see below).

```
Route::get('{company_name}/{table_name?}', 'Apps\SetupController@index')->name('choose_table');
```